# Changes to weight painting in 2.81

Tags: weight-painting

Any insights on changes to weight painting in 2.81?
I had just gotten 2.8 figured out - how to set it up so that I could pose a bone in pose mode, then click on the mesh to go to weight paint mode, and select a bone in weight paint mode as I adjust weights. Although the overall interface is MUCH better, it was easier to adjust a bone in weight paint mode in 2.79.

And it's changed again in 2.81. So that I have to put the armature in object mode before selecting the mesh, which sure slows the process down. Is there another setting involved?

Comment: If I select the armature then shift+select the mesh in object mode, then switch to weight paint mode it works fine for me. I can select the bones and weight paint at the same time. (I'm using right click to select)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I use left click to select, and that may be the problem until someone figures out the workaround. Even so, using left click to select, selecting the armature, then shift+select the mesh, then switch to to weight paint mode, worked in 2.80, if Edit> Lock Object Modes was unchecked. Doesn't work in 2.81.

Comment: I found the answer: can't open the 2.80 file in 2.81 without bugginess - not only the problem with selecting mesh, but odd behavior selecting vertex groups. I opened a clean file in 2.81, appended from the 2.80 file, and all seems reasonably well, as far as I've gotten.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have had an issue with migrating a file from 2.80 to 2.81, but hopefully this helps someone else doing weight painting in 2.81.

In 2.81 with left click select, you should be able to select bones in Weight Paint mode with **Ctrl-Left Mouse**. You shouldn't need to switch to Pose mode to pose any bones.

[image: blender preferences]

For completeness, my full set of steps is:

1. Select the rig
2. Shift-select the mesh
3. Switch to Weight Paint mode
4. Use left click to paint + Ctrl-left click to select bones

Comment: Thank you! Now we're at 2.81.16 and things improve. Yes, that's my workflow too - shift-left click also selects bones. Other discoveries: it's better to open a clean file and append no matter the version. Checking the Topology box in Options, something I used frequently in 2.79, can be a very bad idea now. I haven't figured out a good workflow for copying weights from left to right in an armature that has inconsistent left-right naming - the way I did it in 2.79 causes oddities in subsequent painting with the mirror option on. So, I'm adapting my workflows. :)